# R Plotly - Using ggplotly how to set ggplot() + facet_grid( space = "free_y")

Tags: r, plotly

Using Plotly::ggplotly() facet_grid is not maintaining the space = "free_y" argument. Is it possible to edit the JSON data of the ggplotly object to accomplish what I want? Or is there some other way?

```
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)
library(listviewer)

#create data frame in long format
df <- mtcars %>% rownames_to_column(var = "car") %>% 
  select(car, mpg, disp, cyl) %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = c(mpg, disp))

#create ggplot 
 g <-  ggplot(df) +
    geom_col(aes(x = car, y = value)) +
    facet_grid(
      rows = vars(cyl),
      cols = vars(name),
      scales = "free",
      space = "free_y"
    ) +
    coord_flip()

 #view ggplot plot
 g
```

[image: This is the ggplot graphic]

```
#create plotly plot
 p <- ggplotly(g)

 #view plot
 p
```

As you can see the space = "free_y" argument gets ignored with the below plotly graph

[image: This is the plotly graphic]

I decided to try and edit the JSON to see if it was possible reformat the graph. I can't seem to find the correct line to edit to get the x axis and Y axis labels to match up.

```
#Calculate Variables to change Y facet distribution
 carCountByCycl <- df %>% group_by(cyl) %>% summarise(n = n_distinct(car)) %>% pull(n)
 carRatio <- 1/df %>% summarise(n = n_distinct(car)) %>% pull(n)
 margin <- .005
 a2 <- carRatio * carCountByCycl[1]
 b1 <- a2 + margin
 b2 <- b1 + carRatio * carCountByCycl[2]
 c1 <- b2 + margin

 #Manually edit p yaxis domains
 p$x$layout$yaxis$domain <- c(0, a1 - margin)
 p$x$layout$yaxis2$domain <- c(b1, b2 - margin)
 p$x$layout$yaxis3$domain <- c(c1, 1)

 #See what it looks like
 p
```

[image: Edited Plotly Graphic]

Does anyone have any suggestions? I would really prefer not to loop through the graphics and use plotly::subplot() as this is causing other issues with my real code.

Comment: Hi, have you found any solution for this yet? I'm having the same problem

Comment: Sadly I haven't.